# Get a list of delimited filenames from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I'm really new to Bash, so this could sound silly to most of you.
I'm trying to get a list of some filenames from a text file. Tried to do this with sed and awk, but couldn't get it to work with my limited knowledge.

This is a sample file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 14948)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="471.677px" height="126.604px" viewBox="0 0 471.677 126.604" enable-background="new 0 0 471.677 126.604"
 xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="0.01" y="1.27" fill="none" width="471.667" height="125.333"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0.0098 8.3701)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="10">/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="10">/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf</tspan><tspan x="0" y="24" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="10">/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

What I would like to get from this sample is a new text file with this exact content:

`/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf`
`/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf`
`/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf`

I thought telling sed to print all the matching entries between '`font-size"10">`' and '`</tspan>`' but... the best I got was a file with the whole line contaning my field delimiters.

If you could explain each step done, would be great.

- The filenames could be more or less. This 3 are just an example.

Comment: Are running this on a Mac? Do you have fink or MacPorts installed?  If so, what does "which xsltproc", at the command prompt, tell you?

Comment: For selecting from an XML file, parsing it would be a better option, especially if the tags surrounding the filenames might have different attributes from file to file.  Would you be ok with using something like a python script, or does it have to be bash/awk/sed?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
cat file.xml | sed -e's/^[^>]*>//' -e's/<.*$//' | grep \\.
```

It's not very general-purpose, but to be fully general would be A LOT more complicated (XML requires a full parser, etc.).

Basically, the sed script has two parts.  First, strip off all characters from beginning of line (^) to the first ">" character.  Note that I match all non ">" in order to do that.  The second part strips off all characters from the left most "<" character to the end of line.  Since this second part comes AFTER the first part, it's done after the first stripping is done, that's why it doesn't erase the whole line.

Then, the grep statement returns only lines with a "." in them, which is only the lines with filenames remaining.

Hope that helps!

Comment: sed -e's/^[^>]*>//' -e's/<.*$//' file.xml | grep \\.

extra cat! extra cat! /me points.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` command for this will be

```
 sed  -n 's|font-size="[0-9]*".\(.*\)</tspan.*|\1|p' file.xml
            -------------------  --  ---------
               prefix part       \1   suffix
```

This is how it works,

- The `-n` suppresses printing of all lines from the buffer
- the `p` at the end indicates the replaced buffer is to be printed
- the `'|'` used as a separator instead of the usual `'/'` helps filtering path separators easily
- the search string is matching for all content between `font-size="[0-9]*".` and `

  the part between `\(` and `\)` is the one we are interested in

  - the `\1` indicates we want to retain that in the buffer for the print

This command uses the [group operator which is described here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8).

On your file this gives,

```
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf
```

Note that it is important to get the correct prefix and suffix strings to get all the matches. In your example these are the `font-size` and `tspan` parts i found above. But, that may not be the case with all the file strings in your file. So check that.

Answer (score 0):

Sed and awk are generally not the right way to read XML.  They may work, but the XML can change layout at any time and break things, while still being perfectly valid XML.

Much better is to use something like Perl.  Install the XML::Smart module either via CPAN, or on ubunto with "sudo apt-get install libxml-smart-perl".

Then a simple script like this:

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;

use XML::Smart;

my $xml = XML::Smart->new ("svg.xml") || die "Cannot read XML: $!.";
my $version = $xml->{svg}{version} || die "Cannot determine SVG version.";

foreach my $file ($xml->{svg}{text}{tspan}('@')) {
    print $file->content . "\n";
}
```

Save it as svg.pl.  Save your XML as svg.xml.

$ perl svg.pl
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf

This:

- Parses the XML, checking it is correct.
- Checks that the version exists (just a sanity check really).
- Loops through an array of all svg/text/tspans and prints the content.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Others have given good answers on why you should use a proper XML parser if you want to go around parsing XML, but as far as an explanation on how to accomplish this in sed, in case you come across a similar issue:

```
#Full Command
sed -n 's/^[^<]*<tspan[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/p'  ~/your_file.xml
```

The n option makes sed not send any output unless asked to do so. Normally sed will repeat the pattern space at the end, which can be confusing

Starting off with s, since were [s]ubstituting. The "/" that follows tells sed that we'll be using "/" to divide the different parts of the script.

Grab everything from the beginning of the line (^) along with everything after that is not an open bracket ([^`<]*). This will be discarded later on.

Grab tspan and everything after it that is not a closing bracket ([^>]*>). This will also be discarded.

Grab everything after that closing bracket, that is not an open bracket. This is the part we'll want to keep, so we enclose it in escaped parentheses. "([^<]*)"

Grab everything from that last closing bracket until the end of the line "<.*" . We'll be throwing this away, too.

Second part of the command: \1
All this means is: repeat back whatever was in the first set of escaped parentheses we used earlier. There was only one set of parentheses, so \2, \3, etc are meaningless here, but you might use them in other scripts. In your case, you want to repeat back what we matched from inside your

Lastly: "p" makes sed print out the matches. This works with the -n at the beginning, amounting to "don't print anything 'except' matches"

Hope that was helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have xmlgawk, you can get easily.

```
@load xml

BEGIN {
    XMLMODE = 1;
    XMLCHARSET = "utf-8";
}

XMLCHARDATA {
    data = $0;
}

XMLENDELEM == "tspan" {
    print data;
}
```

and

```
$ xgawk -f pick_from_svg.awk sample.xml 
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="font-size=\"10\">|</tspan>"}/pdf/' xml.txt
```

#### Result

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="font-size=\"10\">|"}/pdf/' xml.txt
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy 2.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1 copy.pdf
/Volumes/Secondary500/Temp/Untitled-2_Layer 1.pdf
```

This code is probably the simplest one yet with no messy regex and it is very extensible and easy for you to adjust it to your likings. I decided to match against the term 'pdf' hence the `/pdf/` portion of the code but if, for example, you had other files that you want to match that aren't pdf's but do contain the word 'Volumes' you can simply use `/Volumes/` instead.